# Issue printing strings from struct in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I am trying to write a program that takes first names and last names from stdin separated by newline and stores them in char arrays inside of a struct array. Everything seems to be working fine until I want to print them in a certain way. I need the names to be formatted like this on the output:
`<lastName>, <firstName>` That is why I added a function to remove the trailing newline from the end of each line when parsing the values. It however does not return anything when doing this:

```
printf("%s, %s",people[0].lastName, people[0].firstName);
```

However when printing the values on seperate lines like

```
printf("%s\n",people[0].lastName);
printf("%s\n",people[0].firstName);
```

or using puts

```
puts(people[0].lastName);
```

it works just fine.
When I comment out the removeNewline() function it seems to get rid of the problem. But with the newline at the end I cannot format the output the way I desribed.
Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 100
#define MAX_PEOPLE 42

struct Person{
  char firstName [MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
  char lastName[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
};

void removeNewline(char * string){
  for(int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(string[i] == '\n'){
      string[i] = '\0';
    }
  }
}

int parseData(struct Person * people){
    int peopleCounter;
    for(peopleCounter = 0; peopleCounter < MAX_PEOPLE; peopleCounter++){
        char firstName[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
        char lastName[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];

      if(fgets(firstName,MAX_STRING_LENGTH,stdin) == NULL){
        break;
      }
      fgets(lastName,MAX_STRING_LENGTH,stdin);
        
      removeNewline(firstName);
      removeNewline(lastName);

      strcpy(people[peopleCounter].firstName,firstName);
      strcpy(people[peopleCounter].lastName,lastName);
    }
    return peopleCounter;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    struct Person people [MAX_PEOPLE];
    parseData(people);

    //PROBLEM
    printf("%s, %s",people[0].firstName, people[0].lastName);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        printperson(people, i);
    }
}
```

I am giving the values from a text file through redirection like so:

```
./main <people.txt
```

```
people.txt example:
George
Washington
Thomas
Jefferson
```

```
desired output:
Washington, George
Jefferson, Thomas
```

Comment: You code doesn't compile as it relies on `printperson()` which you haven't shared with us.

Comment: `printf("%s, %s",people[0].firstName, people[0].lastName);` so you need to swap the arguments if you want the last name first.

Comment: Is that the real code, or just a extract (which would be commendable: minimal reproducible example, or attempt at it, see Allan's first comment?). Because when I see things that prints each time we print them with a new line, and that doesn't when we don't, I start wondering if it is not just a flushing problem. But if that's the real code, then buffers are flushed when program exits, so it would invalidate this hypothesis. But if the program does not really end there, and continues looping on some other tasks after the print... the print without newline is probably just waiting in buffer.

Comment: Are you on windows by any chance with "\r\n"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce the issue.  Here are the minor changes:

1. `removeNewline()`: return after we process the first newline.  Streamlined it a bit.
2. `parseData()`: store directly in struct instead of temporary variables.  Renamed `peopleCounter` to `i` as it was it unnecessary long.  Check return value of 2nd `fgets()`, too.
3. `main()`: Removed call to `printperson()` and looped over the returned values with the two arguments variables switched in the `printf()` statement for the expected order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 100
#define MAX_PEOPLE 42

struct Person{
    char firstName[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    char lastName[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
};

void removeNewline(char *s) {
    for(;;) {
        *s *= (*s != '\n');
        if(!*s++) return;
    }
}

int parseData(struct Person *people){
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < MAX_PEOPLE; i++){
        if(!fgets((people + i)->firstName,MAX_STRING_LENGTH,stdin))
            break;
        removeNewline((people + i)->firstName);
        if(!fgets((people + i)->lastName,MAX_STRING_LENGTH,stdin))
            break;
        removeNewline((people + i)->lastName);
    }
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct Person people[MAX_PEOPLE];
    int n = parseData(people);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s, %s\n", people[i].lastName, people[i].firstName);
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
Washington, George
Jefferson, Thomas
```